# python reportlab barcode code128 size

Tags: python-3.x, barcode, reportlab, code128

i want to create a label (57*32mm) with a code128 barcode.
Its all fine but the barcode is to small =(
How can i make this barcode bigger ?

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code128
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

c = canvas.Canvas("test.pdf")
c.setPageSize((57*mm,32*mm))
barcode = code128.Code128("123456789")
barcode.drawOn(c, 2*mm, 20*mm)
c.showPage()
c.save()
```

Comment: addition: the size should be fix. So barcodes with different values should be have the same size.

Answer (score 3):

By looking up the source code for reportlab on GitHub, I found out that the barcode object has a width property.
By simply using

```
canvas.saveState()
canvas.translate(2*cm, 3*cm) # bottom left corner of the barcode
canvas.scale(15*cm / barcode.width, 2*cm / barcode.height) # resize (15 cm and 2 cm)
barcode.drawOn(canvas, 0, 0)
canvas.restoreState()
```

You can obtain the obtain of the exact size you desire.

Answer (score 3):

The total width of the barcode is bar_width * total_char_widths + quiet space
So.. the correct barWidth can be determined by

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code128
final_size = 100 # arbitrary
# setting barWidth to 1
initial_width = .1

barcode128 = code128.Code128(barcode_value, humanReadable=True, barWidth=initial_width,
                             barHeight=1)
# creates the barcode, computes the total size
barcode128._calculate()
# the quiet space before and after the barcode
quiet = barcode128.lquiet + barcode128.rquiet
# total_wid = barWidth*charWid + quiet_space
# char_wid = (total_width - quiet) / bar_width
char_width = (barcode128._width - quiet) / barcode128.barWidth
# now that we have the char width we can calculate the bar width
bar_width = (final_size - quiet) / char_width
# set the new bar width
barcode128.barWidth = bar_width
# re-calculate
barcode128._calculate()

# draw the barcode on the canvas
wid, hgt = barcode128._width, barcode128._height
x_pos = y_pos = final_size # arbitrary
barcode128.drawOn(your_canvas, x_pos, y_pos)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the barcode size by barHeight and barWidth:

```
barcode = code128.Code128("123456789",barHeight=.9*inch,barWidth = 1.2)
```

Comment: hi is there realy no way to set the barcode to a fix size ??

Answer (score 1):

I finaly found the answer to that with other bits of non-working snipet of code

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import code128
from reportlab.lib.units import mm, inch, cm, pica
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

code = "asdasda" #remove this if in function
c = canvas.Canvas(f"{code}.pdf")
page_width = 550  # page width
# add specific unit here as x= num*unit
# pica,mm and no unit works, I don't know why the 2 other don't
page_height = 200  # page height
# add specific unit here as x= num*unit
# pica,mm and no unit works, I don't know why the 2 other don't
margin_y = 10  # top/bottom margin
# add specific unit here as x= num*unit
# pica,mm and no unit works, I don't know why the 2 other don't

bar_height = page_height - (margin_y * 2)  # barcode line height

bar_width = page_width / (11 * len(str(code)) + 55)  # barcode individual width has the formula
# page width / (11*string_length) + 55   ##(I also saw +35 but in my test it was not working)


c.setPageSize((page_width, page_height))  # set page to said mesure
humanReadable = True  # with or without text
barcode = code128.Code128(code,
                          barHeight=bar_height,
                          barWidth=bar_width,
                          humanReadable=humanReadable)

drawon_x = 0  # x value for drawing already has a margin (not like Y) bar with formula account for that
if humanReadable:
    drawon_y = page_height - margin_y - bar_height  # if text reduce bar height to hace the correct value
else:
    drawon_y = page_height - bar_height  # set draw point to the top of the page - the height of the drawn barcode
barcode.drawOn(c, drawon_x, drawon_y)  # do the drawing

c.save()  # save pdf
```

if you want multiple separate barcode pas a list of code like this

```
def createSinglePDFBarcode(code):
    #code from above here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import random
    import string

    num = 5

    # Generate {num} random numbers between 10 and 30
    # printing uppercase
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    randomSList =[] #list of code you want as barcode
    for x in range(num):
        randomSList.append(''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10)))
    for x in randomSList: # for each code make a barcode
        createSinglePDFBarcode(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

None of this seemed to work for me so I went digging myself. On this site, I found a calculator which gives the formula for working out the length of code128 and code39 barcodes:
https://www.traceability.com/calculators/7-code-128-barcode-length-calculator
https://www.traceability.com/calculators/6-code-39-barcode-length-calculator

Since I was using code39, I took the equation it listed for code39 and rearranged it for "X", using the stated assumption that "I" = "X". Since the default ratio between wide and narrow elements in reportlab is 2.2, you can rearrange the whole equation to give "X" (the bar width) terms of only "L" and "C" where "L" is the desired overall width of the barcode and "C" is the number of characters.

To save you some maths, the rearrangement gives:

X = L / (13.6*C + 26.2)

From there, coding this became easy:

```
# Stores the string to but inputted into the barcode
bcString = "EXAMPLE-XXX"
# Sets the intended width
codeWid = 78
# Calculates the necessary bar width in mm
barwid = codeWid / ((13.6*len(str(bcString)))+26.2)
# Creates a variable for the code39 job barcode
bar39JNR = code39.Extended39(bcString, barWidth = barwid*mm)
```

Hope this helps you all in future.